# Time, Date and Battery Power Font : Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

The date time and battery font on the top bar appear very thin. Attaching a screenshot

[image]

If I remember correctly, these items were displayed in bold font and were quite thick, in Ubuntu 18.04. How can I change the date, time and battery thing to be bold. Going to tweaks and Changing the font to bold really doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, I tried till now but not able to catch the point but here is a small thing that you can understand https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/07/finally-change-gnome-shell-font-interface

Comment: It's ok. Thanks for the kind help.

Comment: I am just using the "MyCustomeTheme" as you pointed out in your answer.

Comment: Yes, basically go with it and make the top bar font bold.

Comment: Sure thanks, and thanks for all the kind help.